# Edit operation with radioButtons

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

The model is IEnumerable of RatingSource

```
public class RatingSource
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Source { get; set; }

        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }
```

View code:

```
@foreach (var ratingSource in Model)
 {
     <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => ratingSource.Source)  
        </td>
        <td>
             @Html.RadioButton("Active",ratingSource.Id,ratingSource.IsActive)
        </td>
     </tr>
 }
```

I dont use EditorForModel for IsActive because it gives checkBoxes.
How could I save Edited data to DB?
I use EntityFramework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I was able to fetch out the selected RatingSource

**Controller Code:**

```
    public ViewResult SaveInfo()
    {            
        return View(lstRatingSources);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ViewResult SaveInfo()
    {
        var formValue = Request.Form["Active"];
        int Id = Convert.ToInt32(formValue);
        RatingSource selectedRatingResource = 
                     lstRatingSources.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == Id);
        return View("AcknowledgementView");
    }
```

**View Code:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<table>
@foreach (var ratingSource in Model)
{
     <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => ratingSource.Source)  
        </td>
        <td>
             @Html.RadioButton("Active", ratingSource.Id, ratingSource.IsSelected)
        </td>
     </tr>
}
<tr><td><input type="submit" value="Save Info" /></td><td></td></tr>
 </table>
}
```

Please don't ask why I use `Request.Form["Active"]`, this is 2 AM and I didn't go in finding detail. Just get that by doing quick watch of Request.Form object. Hope this helps you.

Comment: What is lstRatingSources? And I got an error: 2 actions with the same names and parametres.

Comment: What I have to do next with selectedRatingResource?

Comment: lstRatingSources is your IEnumerable collection of RatingSource. I took a List <>.  Now u can pass selectedRatingResource to ur EF and save.